# Unbolding sans serif font in math mode

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

Is there a way to "unbold" the default text font (namely, sans serif) when written in math mode? Consider this example:

Hello World$\qquad\textsf{Hello World}$

The first instance of "Hello World" is just plain text; the second is obtained inside math mode using the `\textsf` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell MathJax to use the same font as is used for the surrounding text by the following command:

`$\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{Some text}}$`

This gives: 
$\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{Some text}}$

This assumes that what  you want is to have the same font as the text, which happens to be a sans-serif font at the moment. In case this main font should change in the future or somebody changes it locally via using a custom style-file the text above will also change.

If the intent would be to "force" a sans-serif font, just one that usually is less bold, then this can be done using:

`$\style{font-family:sans-serif;}{\text{Some other text}}$`

This gives: 
$\style{font-family:sans-serif;}{\text{Some other text}}$

I learned this from an answer by [regret on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20554), and the comments below.

Comment: Or just `$\style{font-family:"sans-serif";}{\text{Hello!}}$` to ensure sans serif regardless of the inherited font family.

Comment: Strangely it seems not to work $\style{font-family:"sans-serif";}{\text{Hello!}}$ maybe like so  $\style{font-family:sans-serif;}{\text{Hello!}}$. // The quotation marks need to go. But thanks regardless.

Comment: Well, it's not the same sans serif font as used on MO, but it is sans serif. (Both work for me, with the same output.)

Comment: No, for me it is a serif-font. I am not sure you saw the updated comment. I think there should be no quotes.

Comment: On another device it is sans-serif for me too. One more test $\text{Test}$ $\style{font-family:"serif";}{\text{serifquote}}$ $\style{font-family:serif;}{\text{serifnoquote}}$ $\style{font-family:"sans-serif";}{\text{sanserifquote}}$ $\style{font-family:sans-serif;} {\text{sanserifnoquote}}$ Very weird.

Comment: The standard says (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html, 15.3) that "generic font family names are keywords and must NOT be quoted", so quid is right. If you put "sans-serif" in quotes, it selects an actual font with this exact name rather than the generic sans-serif font. This happens to work in SOME system configuration (e.g., based on fontconfig) because of the way they implement generic families (namely, by providing a font name alias), but this is unreliable and fails on other systems.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek This explains it nicely. I update the answer a bit. Thanks to both of you for the additional information.